# Dell FX100 KVM Host card clobbers onboard audio

Tags: audio, ubuntu-10.04, kvm-switch, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision server with a PCIe FX100 KVM Host card installed (manufacturer is Teradici but it's rebranded as a Dell solution.)

I am not using this card (it's installed in the machine but not externally connected to anything), but I believe it's still overriding the onboard audio to be the default, and only, audio output. As such, the audio from the server is being routed to the KVM card. I do not want this to happen as I have speakers connected to the audio out jack.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, and under System -> Preferences -> Sound, the only thing listed is "HDA Teradici", which is the KVM card.

According to the server's manual, the onboard audio is supposed to be "an integrated two-chip audio solution comprised of Sigmatel’s STAC9200 High Definition Audio CODEC and the ESB2’s integrated AC97/High Definition digital controller".

- **Where can I select to use the onboard audio instead of the KVM card, or how can I find where the PCI card is overriding the onboard sound?**
- If that's not possible, is it possible to disable the PCIe KVM card somehow? This is a remote machine so I'm not able to physically remove the card.

I would also appreciate any troubleshooting steps to point me in the right direction for where this card may be overriding things, any relevant logs, etc.

---

### `lspci` output

`lspci` lists the following for the device, **but does not appear to list any other audio devices** (using `lspci -v | grep Audio`):

```
02:00.0 USB Controller: Teradici Corp. Device 1200
02:00.1 Audio device: Teradici Corp. Device 1200
```

---

### `lshw` output

and `lshw` has the following relevant section:

```
*-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 5400 Chipset PCI Express Port 5
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
         version: 20
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:73 memory:dbf00000-dbffffff
       *-usb
            description: USB Controller
            product: Teradici Corp.
            ...
            configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=0
            resources: irq:52 memory:dbffb000-dbffbfff
       *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: Teradici Corp.
            vendor: Teradici Corp.
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
            resources: irq:52 memory:dbffc000-dbffffff
```

---

### `pacmd list-cards` output

and `pacmd list-cards` Lists only one card available (Which is why I'd assume I'm unable to select any others):

```
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> 1 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_02_00.1>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 4
properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Teradici"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Teradici at 0xdbffc000 irq 52"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:02:00.1"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/0000:02:00.1/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "6549"
    device.vendor.name = "Teradici Corp."
    device.product.id = "1200"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "HDA Teradici"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060)
    input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60)
    off: Off (priority 0)
active profile: <output:analog-stereo>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_02_00.1.analog-stereo/#0: HDA Teradici Analog Stereo
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_02_00.1.analog-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of HDA Teradici Analog Stereo
>>>
```

---

### `aplay` output

And `aplay -l` similarly only lists the Teradici device:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Teradici [HDA Teradici], device 0: ALC883 Analog [ALC883 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

### `alsa-details` script output

I've run the alsa-details script, the results are available in [this paste](http://pastebin.com/PfVLqrG7).

Comment: What happens if you simply remove the KVM card?

Comment: @harrymc This is a (very) remote server in an awkwardly placed rack, but I'm trying to get someone to do just this. The other option is that the onboard audio is disabled in the BIOS, but I built this server a couple of years back and wouldn't have intentionally done that.

Comment: You could have a look at [this article](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/06/how-to-fix-no-sound-problems-on-ubuntu.html).

Comment: @harrymc The only command there that would appear useful is `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic` to attempt to reinstall the sound modules. However, this server is not internet-facing, so I'd have to do this offline, which would be a real pain. Surely failing to load the appropriate sound modules (or them being unloaded) should be logged somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the KVM card removed from the server and the onboard audio was automatically detected. This card obviously isn't very well supported in Linux, so for anyone coming across this, I would suggest you go with an external KVM solution that isn't tied to your specific server hardware.

Answer (score 0):

A card or motherboard circuit going suddenly undetected is a hard problem to find.

As you say that this is a static production server with no software or hardware modifications, this should not be a driver error. Unless if some software was installed/updated, I would go for hardware instead of software.

But for the case of a hardware problem with the onboard audio, nobody on this forum can really help.

Comment: Note: For a server stashed away in a hole for a long while, dirt could also be a problem.